# How to mint using standard ERC721

Tags: erc-20, erc-721, erc

I couldn't find such mint, burn functions on the ERC721, ERC20, ERC1155 standard.
Should developer add these function by themselves?
Why wasn't it considered when the standard protocols were made?

Thank you.

Comment: I wouldnt say it wasnt considered, but rather they are upgradeable, if you check openZeppelin contracts those are virtual functions, meaning is for the user to override accordingly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is the responsibility of the implementer to add these functions.

In the [specification](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-721) there is justification why these are not included in the standard:

> Creation of NFTs (“minting”) and destruction of NFTs (“burning”) is not included in the specification. Your contract may implement these by other means. Please see the event documentation for your responsibilities when creating or destroying NFTs.